# gstreamer audio error on linux

Tags: linux, gstreamer

i am using g streamer-0.10 on Ubuntu os for streaming an web cam video on to an rtmp server i am getting an video output  but their is a problem in audio . Below command used for streaming

> gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src  ! videoscale method=0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=852,height=480,framerate=(fraction)24/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc pass=pass1 threads=0 bitrate=900 tune=zerolatency ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://..../live/testing' demux.  alsasrc device="hw:0,0" ! audioresample !  audio/x-raw-int,rate=48000,channels=2,depth=16 !  pulseaudiosink
>   Blockquote

by running the above command i got an error

> gstbaseaudiosrc.c(840): gst_base_audio_src_create (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:
>   Dropped 13920 samples. This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly.
>   Blockquote

so the audio is not audible.

Help me out to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance
Ameeth

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your pipeline. What is "demux." in the middle?
The problem you are facing is because you have not seperated your elements with queues. Keep a queue before your sinks and after your sources to give the rest all seperate threads to run. It should allow get rid of the issue.

Since I don't have pulse audio or rtmp reciever in my system i have tested out the following and it works.

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! ffmpegcolorspace ! queue ! x264enc pass=pass1 threads=0 bitrate=900000 tune=zerolatency ! queue ! flvmux name=mux ! fakesink  alsasrc ! queue ! audioresample !  audioconvert !  queue ! autoaudiosink
```

You can change it accordingly and use it. The only thing I had to do to make it work and remove the error your are facing is to add the queues.

Answer (score 0):

For me (Logitech c920 on Raspberry Pi3 w/ GStreamer 1.4.4) I was able to get rid of the "Dropped samples" warning by using `audioresample` to set the sampling rate of the `alsasrc` to something that `flvmux` liked. From `gst-inspect-1.0 flvmux`, it looks like `flvmux` only supports `5512, 11025, 22050, 44100` sample rates for x-raw and `5512, 8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 44100` for mp4. Here's my working pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e \
    uvch264src initial-bitrate=800000 average-bitrate=800000 iframe-period=2000 device=/dev/video0 name=src auto-start=true \
    src.vidsrc ! video/x-h264,width=864,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! mux. \
    alsasrc device=hw:1 ! 'audio/x-raw, rate=32000, format=S16LE, channels=2' ! queue ! audioresample ! "audio/x-raw,rate=44100" ! queue ! voaacenc bitrate=96000 ! mux. \
    flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location="rtmp://live-sea.twitch.tv/app/MYSTREAMKEY"
```

I was surprised that `flvmux` didn't complain about getting an audio source that was at an unsupported sampling rate. Not sure if that's expected behavior.